# How to get command line client to start with shell>

Tags: mysql, sql, database

MySql command line client once loaded asks for a password, when entered I automatically get directed to a localhost database which starts with mysql> how do I change this to shell> or am I looking at the totally wrong thing?

Comment: What would 'shell' represent, just a customized interface?

Comment: I am following this tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting-disconnecting.html
I can not run this code on my current command line therefore, think that mysql> may be the problem.

Comment: In that tutorial - `shell>` is actually the prompt for the standard command line, which for you might be `your-username>` or something similar.  It's what you start with when you open a console window.

Comment: When I start my MySql console I get a password request, when I enter MySql password the console window starts with mysql>

Comment: What are you using to start MySql console?  Double clicking an icon/executable, or opening a command-line console window and typing 'mysql'?

Comment: Opening executable from start->myprograms->mysql->mysql server 5.6->mysql5.6 command line client 
should I be doing this from the windows command terminal?

Comment: Yes, you should use the terminal - that is what the tutorial is using (and where it is displaying `shell>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is customize the prompt, you can simply set the `MYSQL_PS1` env variable:

```
export MYSQL_PS1="shell> "
```